# Class being ignored in django forms.py file

Tags: html, css, django, tailwind-css

The 'class' attribute I set on my widgets in the `forms.py` file are being ignored in my html file when I render `{{ form.field_type }}`. The `placeholder` attribute is working correctly, I tested changing the text and it is coming through on my form. For some reason the class styling isn't.

Do I need to do something other than `{{ form.title }}` to get the styling to come through? I'm using Tailwind CSS

forms.py:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['title'].label = ""
        self.fields['description'].label = ""
        self.fields['url_link'].label = ""
        self.fields['url_link'].required = False


    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'url_link']
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': "title w-full bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 p-2 mb-4 outline-none",
                                            'spellcheck': "false", 'placeholder': "Title", 'type': "text"}),
            'description': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': "description w-full bg-gray-100 sec p-3 h-60 border border-gray-300 outline-none",
                                                 'spellcheck': "false", 'placeholder': "Describe everything about this post here", 'type': "text"}),
            'url_link': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={'class': "title w-full bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 p-2 mb-4 outline-none",
                       'spellcheck': "false", 'placeholder': "Link to article (optional)", 'type': "text"}),
        }
```

html file:

```
  <div class="editor mx-auto w-10/12 flex flex-col text-gray-800 border border-gray-300 p-4 shadow-lg max-w-2xl">
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.title }}
        {{ form.description }}
        <div class="icons flex text-gray-500 m-2">
            <div class="count ml-auto text-gray-400 text-xs font-semibold">0/500</div>
        </div>
        {{ form.url_link }}
</div>
```

Comment: Consider checking the `forms.py` is covered by the `content` file globs in the Tailwind configuration.

Comment: How would I find the tailwind content file?

Comment: `forms.py` would be a Tailwind content file since it contains Tailwind classes.